# Create column with positive and negative adding up index based on certain row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (sample):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['A', False, 2], ['A', True, 8], ['A', False, 25], ['A', False, 30], ['B', False, 4], ['B', False, 8], ['B', True, 2], ['B', True, 1], ['B', False, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['group', 'indicator', 'val'])

  group  indicator  val
0     A      False    2
1     A       True    8
2     A      False   25
3     A      False   30
4     B      False    4
5     B      False    8
6     B       True    2
7     B       True    1
8     B      False    3
```

I would like to add a column called `idx`, which has values `0` for the rows with `True` and a negative adding up values before (backward filling) the `0` and a positive adding up values after (forward filling) the `0` per `group`. I started with using the following which does the job of adding a `0` for certain rows, but I don't know how to do the cumulative filling part:

```
# add zero index to rows with True
df.loc[df['indicator'] == True, 'idx'] = 0
# cumulative filling per group
df.groupby('group')['idx'].fillna(1).cumsum()
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
data = [['A', False, 2, -1], ['A', True, 8, 0], ['A', False, 25, 1], ['A', False, 30, 2], ['B', False, 4, -2], ['B', False, 8, -1], ['B', True, 2, 0], ['B', True, 1, 0], ['B', False, 3, 1]]
df_desired = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['group', 'indicator', 'val', 'idx'])

  group  indicator  val  idx
0     A      False    2   -1
1     A       True    8    0
2     A      False   25    1
3     A      False   30    2
4     B      False    4   -2
5     B      False    8   -1
6     B       True    2    0
7     B       True    1    0
8     B      False    3    1
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to do the positive negative cumulative filling part per group using `pandas`?

Comment: What will happen if you have two Trues in the same group which are not close to each other? Should the values between them be negative or positive? And it seems like there is an order for each group - does it being represented by the index?

Comment: @Roim, You can assume that that never happens. So the Trues are always close to each other per group in the data.

Comment: @Roim, Yes there is an order for each group which is represented by the index. So maybe a difference calculation using index is an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an extra column named `sign` and used `.cumsum()` and a reversed version of `.cumsum()` to create the column `idx`:

```
# create column sign
df.loc[df['indicator'] == True, 'sign'] = -1
df['sign'] = df.groupby(['group'])['sign'].bfill()

df.loc[df['indicator'] == True, 'sign'] = 1
df['sign'] = df.groupby(['group'])['sign'].ffill()

df.loc[df['indicator'] == True, 'sign'] = 0

# create column idx
df.loc[df.sign == 1, 'idx'] = df[df.sign == 1].groupby(['group']).sign.cumsum()
df.loc[df.sign == 0, 'idx'] = 0
df.loc[df.sign == -1, 'idx'] = df[df.sign == -1][::-1].groupby(['group']).sign.cumsum()[::-1]
# remove column sign and make column idx integer value
df['idx'] = df['idx'].astype(int)
df = df.drop(columns='sign')
```

Output:

```
  group  indicator  val  idx
0     A      False    2   -1
1     A       True    8    0
2     A      False   25    1
3     A      False   30    2
4     B      False    4   -2
5     B      False    8   -1
6     B       True    2    0
7     B       True    1    0
8     B      False    3    1
```

Comment: @T C Molenaar, Bedankt! It worked perfectly. A created approach using the sign column.